# How to create a DataFrame with two subsequent boolean indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas DataFrame containing sales of 3 stores per week. I need to filter the sales that happened in the most recent month of the most recent year.

I have created two additional columns in the DataFrame: one containing year, the other containing month. Then I created a variable containing the most recent year and filtered my original DataFrame by this variable by using boolean indexing. Then I wanted to repeat this step: create a variable containing the most recent month of the most recent year and create a second data frame by filtering for this most recent month. However, when I try to do the second step (filter the DataFrame with the most recent year by the most recent month), I keep getting error messages.

Here is the original DataFrame:

```
    week        storeA  storeB  storeC  
0   2014-05-04  2643    8257    3893        
1   2014-05-11  6444    5736    5634        
2   2018-05-18  9646    2552    4253        
3   2018-06-25  5960    10740   8264        
4   2018-06-01  7412    7374    3208
```

I am able to create two additional columns containing year and month

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['week']).month 
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['week']).year
```

After this, my DataFrame looks like this:

```
    week        storeA  storeB  storeC  year  month
0   2014-05-04  2643    8257    3893    2014  05    
1   2014-05-11  6444    5736    5634    2014  05
2   2018-05-18  9646    2552    4253    2018  05
3   2018-06-25  5960    10740   8264    2018  06
4   2018-06-01  7412    7374    3208    2018  06
```

Then I create a variable containing the max year and create a new date frame with the max year:

```
max_year = df['year'].max()
df_last_year = df[df['year']== max_year]
```

Now I want to repeat the same step in order to filter for the max month. I create a new variable containing the max month:

```
max_month = df_last_year['month'].max()
```

However, when I try to create a new data frame, just like I did with max_year, I get the following error message:

```
df_last_month = df[df_last_year['month']==max_month]
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: It's a typo, `df[df_last_year['month']==max_month]` should be `df_last_year[df_last_year['month']==max_month]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do it?**

Use:

```
df_last_year[df_last_year['month']==max_month]
```

or alternative:

```
df_last_month=df_last_year.where(df_last_year['month']==max_month).dropna()
df_last_month
```

Output:

```
week    storeA  storeB  storeC  year    month
3   2018-06-25  5960.0  10740.0 8264.0  2018.0  6.0
4   2018-06-01  7412.0  7374.0  3208.0  2018.0  6.0
```

**Why I get an error?**

```
df['year']== max_year
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: year, dtype: bool

df_last_year['year']== max_month
```

Output:

```
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: year, dtype: bool
```

This series is missing Boolean for index = 0 and index = 1 and therefore cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: `df_last_month = df[df_last_year['month']==max_month]`

Type: `df_last_month = df_last_year[df_last_year['month']==max_month]`

You were basically trying to slice a data frame based on another data frame's column value.

Or: `df_last_month = df[df['month']==max_month]`, based on the data frame you want to slice from.